# Odoo 17: create parent child record in another table on Save

Tags: automation, odoo

in **Automation Rules** we do not have Triggers like Before Create but there is **On Save** which work fine for **creating record(s) in another table(s)**, but if there is no relation field for Action Create Record and also if i want to create parent-child records how it can be done?

i tried using Execute Code as below but it throws error.

Model : **Approval Request**

Trigger : **On Save**

**Execute Code**:

```
if record.request_status=='approved' and record.category_id in (8, 9, 13):

    # Create stock.picking record

    picking_data = {

        'picking_type_id': 1,

        'company_id': 1,

        # Add other required fields

    }

    stock_picking = env['stock.picking'].create(picking_data)



    for approval_line in record.approval_product_line: 

        # Create stock.move record

        move_data = {

            'picking_id': stock_picking.id,

            'product_id': approval_line.product_id.id,

            'product_uom_qty': approval_line.quantity,

            'company_id': 1,

            'product_uom': 1,

            # Add other required fields

        }

    stock_move = env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
```

**error for stock.move**:

ValueError: : "'approval.request' object has no attribute 'approval_product_line'" while evaluating

this is my first attempt to create a parent-child record using python code in Automation Rule, i don't know how to about the child side records in this scenario.

can somebody please help with correction in code for stock.move where i want to create Line records which can be multiple as i am totally blank here.

regards

please note: there is an another Automation Rule exists for On Save trigger for same Model mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

it has been done, i am using below code to create Internal Transfer records successfully, the juniors like me can get benefit.

---

```
#raise UserError(f'{record.request_status} - {record.category_id.id}')

if record.request_status=='approved' and record.category_id.id in (8, 9, 13):

    new_stock_picking = env['stock.picking'].create({

      'picking_type_id': 1,

      'company_id': 1,

    })



    for approval_line in record.product_line_ids: 

        # Create stock.move record

        move_data = {

            'picking_id': new_stock_picking.id,

            'picking_type_id': 5,

            'product_id': approval_line.product_id.id,

            'product_uom_qty': approval_line.quantity,

            'name': approval_line.product_id.name,

            'company_id': 1,

            'product_uom': 1,

            'location_id': 1,

            'location_dest_id': 1,

            # Add other required fields

        }

        stock_move = env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
```

a request to seniors: please have a look and advise for betterment.

regards