# Odoo: how to create a link in chatter to redirect to another form view

Tags: redirect, odoo, odoo-17

working for Approvals, i have created an Automation Rule which works fine to generate Internal Transfer records, please refer to my previous topic below:

[Link to previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77837292/odoo-17-create-parent-child-record-in-another-table-on-save)

now **i want to add a link in Chatter to open Internal Transfer form view for newly created record**, like odoo system does this for Inventory, for example.

[image]

how i can do this? please help.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to let odoo create the message on the desired record. You need both the origin record and the destination record. Models are irrelevant in this case, except for one condition: the model which will get the message needs the chatter (`mail.thread` mixin).

An example can be found in Odoo's invoice creation from sales order [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/294a37b0a31ec88165da596c3f3e2dd6f6cb735d/addons/sale/models/sale_order.py#L1408-L1412)

```py
move.message_post_with_source(
    'mail.message_origin_link',
    render_values={'self': move, 'origin': move.line_ids.sale_line_ids.order_id},
    subtype_xmlid='mail.mt_note',
)
```

`move` is the created invoice. In this case `origin` will be retrieved by the line ids order line relation.

Odoo uses a default QWeb template to fill the body of the message. You can also define you're own and use it in `message_post_with_source()`.

To conclude this answer in regards of your other linked question (with your own answer) it should look like this:

```py
if record.request_status=='approved' and record.category_id.id in (8, 9, 13):
    new_stock_picking = env['stock.picking'].create({
        # picking data
    })
    for approval_line in record.product_line_ids: 
        # Create stock.move record
        move_data = {
            # move line data
        }
        stock_move = env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
    # add a message with link to new picking
    record.message_post_with_source(
        'mail.message_origin_link',
        render_values={'self': record, 'origin': new_stock_picking},
        subtype_xmlid='mail.mt_note',
    )
```

Because you're linking on the creating record (approval) to the created record (picking/transfer), the used QWeb template `mail.message_origin_link` probably is not the best fit.

Comment: thanks @CZoellner for detailed reply with guidance, i am not an experienced so most of the mistakes are due to lack of knowledge and understanding, i always realize it. will check this for sure and give feedback. due to client's urgency i added a custome field to hold the id field value of stock.picking within approval.request and implemented a smart button with conditions, it works fine but i am curious how i can have a clickable link within message. now i will try as per your instructions. with best regards

Comment: i copy paste your code just to look first how it works, and its fine, the link appeared in message with the value of name field of Internal Transfer screen and redirect to correct record. 2 thumbs up!! will check it further.

Comment: just a question, can i add my custom message instead of odoo default... if yes, how it can be achieved too...

Comment: You have to create you own template like Odoo's default template. Try to find the default and look into that module to find out to create such templates.

Comment: thank you, will try to do as instructed.